# What's wrong with my code to go to a child state in UI Router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Let's say I've configured an state as follows:

```
{
  name: "results",
  parent: "modules/globalSearch/main",
  url: ""
  // other settings
}
```

<sup>* **Note that I'm not using URLs. "modules/globalSearch/main" is the actual state name**</sup>

In the other hand, "modules/globalSearch/main" is configured as follows:

```
$stateProvider.state({
    name: "modules/globalSearch/main",
    abstract: true
    // other settings
});
```

Since `"results"` is a child of `"modules/globalSearch/main"`, I would expect to call `$state.go` as follows:

```
$state.go("modules/globalSearch/main.results");
```

But UI Router will say that it can't transition to such state, and I can do so if I just call `$state.go("results")`.

What's wrong here?

Comment: @davidxxx I checked your deleted answer. I'm not using URLs, it's the actual state name :(

Comment: It is which I supposed. So I delete it :)

Comment: @davidxxx Yeah, thank you anyway for the effort!

Comment: :) But why do you have names with slashes ? Without slashes in the name, it is working?

Comment: @davidxxx Uhm, because I've implemented a modular UI application framework in my company, and I would like to clearly separate views from different modules. Understand modules as packages like accounting, customers...

Comment: @davidxxx My concern is that it seems like nesting views with dots or using `parent` property might produce different behaviors when navigating to states...

Comment: @davidxxx So you would expect that state name should be **modules/globalSearch/main.results** while it'll be **results**, wouldn't you?

Comment: I have not a lot of experience with parent state but I note the information. Conceptually, if `globalSearch` is the name of a parent state  and `results` is one of its child states, it makes `results` to belong to a specific space : which one of `globalSearch`.
 I found the separation is there. About the separation between distincts module, I think that the separation in the code, the level of coupling between them  and the layout of your folders are the most important.

Comment: @davidxxx Absolutely. And about the parent-childs, `results` is correctly configured as a child of `globalSearch`. No problem here... It's just it seems like configuring them this way it prevents a given app to navigate to a child state using dot syntax... I've opened an issue to clarify this: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/3181

Answer (score 0):

Try $state.go("modules.globalSearch.main.results");

EDIT : 
By the way, I don't know how you declared your states in config.js

but that should stand this form:

```
.state('parent', {
    url : '/parent',
    templateUrl : 'url
})

.state('parent.child', {
    url : '/child/:parameter/',
    templateUrl : 'url
})
```

BR

Comment: **Could not resolve 'modules/globalSearch/main.results' from state'** :(

Comment: About the config, not necessarily. I'll edit my question to provide more background

Comment: Aww well I don't know this syntax ! Sorry I can't help more ! :/

Comment: Yeah I've seen that now official UI Router docs don't mention this approach anymore, but I've checked the source code on GitHub and it's still implemented...